# using Freeswitch ESL Api originate a call to sip remote softphone in java

Tags: java, sip, freeswitch, fusionpbx

### I want to dial a call to sip remote softphone and bridge it to another sip remote softphone using Freeswitch ESL API in java.

currently, I'm using the originate API command to initiate a call and then bridge to direct it to another softphone,

```
EslMessage response = client.sendSyncApiCommand("bgapi originate ", "sofia/internal/1011@178.128.45.171 &bridge(sofia/internal/1012@178.128.45.171)");
```

but none of the phones rang or gets any notification and after a timeout, I got the response `NO_USER_RESPONSE`. or `DESTINATION_OUT_OF_ORDER`